# Django view with simple GET method results in TypeError

Tags: python, django

Using a very simplistic subclass of `django.views.View` I  get a `TypeError` with `__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` as the error message.

urls.py is:

```py
from myapp import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('webhook/', views.Webhook, name='myapp-webhook'),
]
```

views.py:

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseForbidden
from django.views import View

class Webhook(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """We don't provide GET access here."""
        # return 403 (Forbidden)
        return HttpResponseForbidden()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # return 200 (OK)
        return HttpResponse()
```

tests.py:

```py
from django.test import TestCase

class WebhookTests(TestCase):
    def test_get_method_is_forbidden(self):
        response = self.client.get('/webhook')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 403)
```

Now, either accessing `/webhook` in a browser or running `./manage.py test` results in:

```
Internal Server Error: /webhook/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I'm surely missing something here. Pointers to what this is, are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('webhook/', views.Webhook, name='myapp-webhook'),
]
```

Use `views.Webhook.as_view()`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('webhook/', views.Webhook.as_view(), name='myapp-webhook'),
]
```

Comment: Thanks. This works as expected and also reveals that the URI in the test method was missing a trailing "/" (which resulted in a 301 redirect leading to the correct address).